# no access to array elements in a class object

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, constructor

I have three classes: `Magazine`, `MagazineEmployee` and `Follower`. And the following task:

> Once changes were published, the state becomes “PublishInProgress”, and Followers will receive notifications from a magazine
> For each object that represents a follower `onUpdate(data)` method should be present, where for `data` will be passed text of the notification.

I thought the logic could be the following - check array of followers and array of articles in the Magazine object and if there are matches in followers' interests and topics of articles, we should send them notifications. But when I tried to get access to elements of the followers array, they are undefined. So if I want to see in console.log array of followers, it's showing:

```
    0: Follower {name: "Mariya", magazine: Magazine, topic: "sport"}
    1: Follower {name: "Maksym", magazine: Magazine, topic: "politics"}
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

But if I write `console.log(this.magazine.followers[0]);` It's undefined.
I don't know how to fix it.
Here's my code:

```js
class Magazine {
    constructor() {
        this.states = [
            "ReadyForPushNotification",
            "ReadyForApprove",
            "ReadyForPublish",
            "PublishInProgress",
        ];
        this.articles = [];
        this.followers = [];
        this.staff = [];

        this.current = this.states[0];
    }
}

class MagazineEmployee {
    constructor(name, role, magazine) {
        this.name = name;
        this.role = role;
        this.magazine = magazine;
        this.magazine.staff.push(this);
    }

    addArticle(article) {
        this.article = article;
        if (this.role !== "manager") {
            this.magazine.articles.push(article);
        }
        if (this.magazine.articles.length >= 5) {
            this.magazine.current = this.magazine.states[1];
        }
    }

    approve() {
        if (
            this.magazine.current === "ReadyForApprove" &&
            this.role === "manager"
        ) {
            console.log(`Hello ${this.name}. You've approved the 
         changes`);
            this.magazine.current = this.magazine.states[2];
        } else if (this.magazine.articles.length < 5 && this.role === "manager") {
            console.log(`Hello ${this.name}. You can't approve. We don't 
         have enough of publications`);
        } else if (
            this.magazine.current === "ReadyForPublish" &&
            this.role === "manager"
        ) {
            console.log(`Hello ${this.name}. Publications have already 
         been approved by you.`);
        } else if (this.magazine.current === "PublishInProgress") {
            console.log(`Hello ${this.name}. While we are publishing we 
         can't do any actions`);
        } else {
            console.log("You do not have permissions to do it");
        }
    }

    publish() {
        if (this.magazine.current === "ReadyForPublish") {
            console.log(`Hello ${this.name}. You've recently published 
        publications.`);
            this.magazine.current = this.magazine.states[3];
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.magazine.current = this.magazine.states[0];
                this.magazine.articles = [];
                console.log(this.magazine);
            }, 60000);
        } else if (this.magazine.current === "PublishInProgress") {
            console.log(`Hello ${this.name}. While we are publishing we 
        can't do any actions`);
        }
    }
}

class Follower {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    subscribeTo(magazine, topic) {
        this.magazine = magazine;
        this.topic = topic;
        this.magazine.followers.push(this);
    }

    unsubscribe() {
        const index = this.magazine.followers.indexOf(this);
        if (index !== -1) {
            this.magazine.followers.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: provide some code please..

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: I think that caller is not defined in the console. So you have to select the element and then access the property. Instead of "this" use the element. Or put the log command in the code, where the caller is defined.

Comment: of course if i try to do this outside the class, it works, but i have to use it inside because it has to work in certain conditions